# Error: no matching function for call to constructor in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

I am making a small program that shows the price of the selected items using constructors, classes, objects and inheritance. However, I am getting two errors for two different constructors in the derived classes, what can I do to solve this problem?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Beverage{
public:
    int cost_of_water, cost_of_sugar;
    Beverage(int x, int y){
    cost_of_water = x;
    cost_of_sugar = y;
    }
    int computeCost(){
    }
    void print(){
    cout<<"The cost of the beverage is: ";
    }
};
class Tea: public Beverage{
public:
    int price_of_tea_leaves;
    Tea(int a){
    price_of_tea_leaves = a;
    }
    int computeCost(){
        int cost = cost_of_sugar + cost_of_water + price_of_tea_leaves;
        return cost;
    }
};
class Coffee: public Beverage{
public:
    int price_of_coffee_powder;
    Coffee(int b){
    price_of_coffee_powder = b;
    }
    int computeCost(){
        int cost = cost_of_sugar + cost_of_water + price_of_coffee_powder;
        return cost;
    }
};
int main(){
    int m,n;
    cout<<"*****Welcome to the cafeteria management system*****";
    cout<<"1 FOR TEA, 2 FOR COFFEE";
    cin>>m;
    if(m = 1){
        Beverage B(10,5);
        Tea T(10);
        B.print();
        T.computeCost();
    }
    else if (m = 2){
       Beverage B(10,5);
       Coffee C(15);
       B.print();
       C.computeCost();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Thank You!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, here is the well functioning code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Beverage{     //base class
public:                 
    int cost_of_water, cost_of_sugar;
    Beverage(int x, int y){     //base class constructor
    cost_of_water = x;
    cost_of_sugar = y;
    }
    int computeCost(){
    }

};
class Tea: public Beverage{     //derived class
public:
    int price_of_tea_leaves;
    Tea(int a):Beverage(10,5){      //derived class constructor
    price_of_tea_leaves = a;
    }
    int computeCost(){
        int cost = cost_of_sugar + cost_of_water + price_of_tea_leaves;
        return cost;
    }
    void print(){
    cout<<"The cost of the tea is: "<<computeCost();
    }
};
class Coffee: public Beverage{    //derived class
public:
    int price_of_coffee_powder;
    Coffee(int b):Beverage(10,5){       //derived class constructor
    price_of_coffee_powder = b;
    }
    int computeCost(){
        int cost = cost_of_sugar + cost_of_water + price_of_coffee_powder;
        return cost;
    }
    void print(){
    cout<<"The cost of the coffee is: "<<computeCost();
    }
};
int main(){
    int m,n;
    cout<<"*****Welcome to the Cafeteria management system*****"<<endl;;
    cout<<"Input 1 for TEA and 2 for COFFEE: ";
    cin>>m;
    if(m == 1){
        Beverage B(10,5);
        Tea T(10);
        T.print();
    }
    else if (m == 2){
       Beverage B(10,5);
       Coffee C(25);
       C.print();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"ByeBye!";
    }
}
```